# Retrieve specific table rows using Java Persistence

Tags: jpa, persistence, jpa-2.0, entitymanager, java-ee-7

I have a table patient_details(patient_id, first_name, last_name, address,date_of_birth, gender, contact_number,occupation). I have generated an entity class and a PersistenceUnit. I can only find an object using its ID:

```
PatientDetails pd = em.find(PatientDetails.class,patient_id);
```

I want to know how to find an object by using other column name(s) instead of just the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on JPQL or JPA Critera.

https://docs.oracle.com/html/E24396_01/ejb3_langref.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjitv.html

Execute Querys:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createQuery%28javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery%29

Answer (score 0):

For example:

if

```
class PatientDetails
 String first_name;
 @Column(",date_of_birth")
 Date birth;
 ...
}
```

then

```
String sql = "SELECT p FROM PatientDetails p where p.first_name = :fname and p.birth > :generation";
Date generation = new Date(int 1980, 0, 1);
TypedQuery<PatientDetails> query = EM.createQuery(sql);
query.setParameter("fname","John");
query.setParameter("generation",generation);
return query.getResultList
```

returns patients called John and born after 1980.

But you should read the links recommended by @pL4Gu33

Comment: Can I use SELECT * instead of p? What is "generation" and its purpose?

Comment: The purpose of generation should be obvious from the description of the expected query result.